# Cobol - Date loop

Tags: loops, date, cobol

How can I implement a loop that will display subsequent months (01/01/2018, 01/02/2018 etc.) x-times? Additionally, how can I set day,month,year as a variable? By the way, I'm new to Cobol.
This is my code I wrote so far

```
 01  YYYYMMDD         Pic 9(8).
 01  Integer-Form     Pic S9(9).
 Move Function Current-Date(1:8) to YYYYMMDD
 Compute Integer-Form = Function Integer-of-Date(YYYYMMDD)
 Add 12 to Integer-Form
 Compute YYYYMMDD = Function Date-of-Integer(Integer-Form)
 Display 'Date: ' YYYYMMDD.
```

EDIT!

```
            PERFORM VARYING Number-Periods FROM 0 BY 1 UNTIL Number-Periods > 36
            DISPLAY ws-current-day, "/", ws-current-month, "/", ws-current-year
            ADD 1 TO  WS-current-month
                IF ws-current-month > 12 THEN
                   COMPUTE ws-current-month = 1
                   ADD 1 TO WS-current-year
                   END-IF
            END-PERFORM
```

Comment: Maybe interesting? [COBOL has a couple  nifty date functions that allow you to add or subtract from a given date.](http://queenofcobol.com/date-function/). I started out with COBOL many decades ago - fond memories. :) There should be some useful date manipulation libraries available.  Many functions with source: http://www.simotime.com/simodate.htm

Comment: Look at `REDEFINES` as a way to access the individual parts of `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: GUYS! I dit it by doing this! I edited question so you can see my code above. Thanks for your help! You're the best! It was so so so easy

Comment: Okay, but i don't know how to write this data to a file. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: @Raven can you tell us exactly what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: @SaggingRufus, well i was trying to do a loop, huh. Now, I need to save output to file

Comment: @Raven: Please post your full solution as answer, mark it as answer and edit your question (removing the EDIT).
Then go on with starting another question for the new topic (again showing what you've tried so far and what is missing [have a look at `SELECT` and `WRITE`].

Comment: You can use PERFORM n TIMES ... END-PERFORM to do simple loops where you won't use the index.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use redefines and 88 to check month:

```
01  YYYYMMDD         PIC 9(8).
01  YYYYMMDD-R REDEFINES YYYYMMDD.
    05  YYYY         PIC 9(4).
    05  MM           PIC 9(2).
        88 VALID-MONTH VALUE 1 2 3 4 5 6
                             7 8 9 10 11 12.
    05  DD           PIC 9(2).
```

Then you can use the 88 in the check (within the PERFORM VARYING as you discovered):

> ```
>   IF NOT VALID-MONTH
>      ... increment year
> ```